# TypeScript - FormData cycling through elements (using getAll() or entries())

Tags: javascript, typescript, xmlhttprequest

I wanted to leave the 'jQuery universe' and use more vanilla JS. Not just to spice things up, I also decided to use Typescript to add the advantages; but here is the problem:

Just before I send the post request, I need to cycle through the elements. Without Typescript I might use things like `formDataElement.entries()` (or just to check 1 element `formDataElement.getAll('keyForMyFirstEntry')`.

But PhpStorm and the compiler tells me, that there ain't properties like 'getAll' or 'entries'

```
V2A-16:area51 v2a$ tsc --out public/js/d3-fileupload.vanilla.js module/Application/assets/ts/d3-vanilla-fileupload.ts
module/Application/assets/ts/d3-vanilla-fileupload.ts(274,12): error TS2339: Property 'getAll' does not exist on type 'FormData'.

V2A-16:area51 v2a$ tsc --out public/js/d3-fileupload.vanilla.js module/Application/assets/ts/d3-vanilla-fileupload.ts
module/Application/assets/ts/d3-vanilla-fileupload.ts(274,36): error TS2339: Property 'entries' does not exist on type 'FormData'.
```

So here are my questions:

- Why does Typescript only supports append in his library (lib.d.ts), or is there a newer Version
- How can I circle through all elements to prepare them for my post request

Code:

```
function FileSelectHandler($event) {
    let $files = $event.target.files || $event.dataTransfer.files;
    let $targetName = $event.target.getAttribute('data-related-element');
    let $relatedElement = document.querySelectorAll('[name="' + $targetName + '"]');
    let $uri = $relatedElement[0].getAttribute('data-upload-uri');
    let $xhr = new ajax();
    if ($files) {
        [].forEach.call(
            $files,
            function ($file) {
                $data.append('file[]', $file);
            }
        );
    }
    $xhr.post(
        $uri,
        $data
    );
}

class ajax {
    [...]
    public post(
        $url: string,
        $data: FormData,
        $callback: (text: any) => any = function() {},
        $async: any = true
    ) {
        let $query = [];
        if ($data !== undefined) {

            /*
             * Please Help... doesn't work
             */

            for (let $key in $data.entries()) {
                $query.push(encodeURIComponent($key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent($data[$key]));
            }
        }
        this.send($url, $callback, 'POST', $query.join('&'), $async)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok - after a bunch of hours and some new grey hairs:

- entry() and getAll() isn't supported by every browser; Safari and IE are missing and that's the reason, typescript support is missing, too!
- everything you need to do with the elements, you have to do **before** appending it to FormData; in this case encodeURIComponent() (and yes, it could be that easy)

But - maybe there is a solution. I'm thinking of a little preview for every object and with this remedy, I need to hold every template for every item available. In that case, a `post-circling option` like in the code at the top would be nice.